# How to cause parameter to default to "Null Value" in BIRT Report?

Tags: parameters, null, birt

In a BIRT report, there are two String Text Box parameters that look the same on the "Edit Parameter" page, and both are empty in the "Default value" box. However, when I select to run the report, one defaults the "Null Value" selection while the other defaults to an empty string. How can I configure which default is used? Neither parameter is used by the data set as they're just text.

[image: String parameters]

Answer (score 0):

Handling null parameters is one of BIRT's weaknesses.
For example, it's not allowed to just keep the default value of a dataset parameter empty.
And if a null is actually passed to a dataset at runtime, BIRT spits out huge useless stack traces telling that this is not supported...
On the Oracle side, NULL and an empty string are equivalent, so I usually use "" as the default value and make sure that a null passed from the context is converted to "" using this little helper:

```
function nvl_mt(x) {
  if (x==null) {
    return "";
  }
  return x;
}
```

To find out why the parameters behave differently, take a look at the XML source, probably you'll find the difference there.

Also note that for each report parameter, BIRT has a default value stored in the .rptdesign and *yet another* default value stored in the corresponding .rptconfig file, which is only used when starting the report from the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I have several reports with similar constraints.

One solution is to use "All" as the default value, and bit if SQL like this. It returns either the single value entered or everything ('All' is not a valid value in CONTCTSM1.OPERATOR_ID, so it will always be a null return.

```
where CONTCTSM1.OPERATOR_ID = ?
or
'All' = ?
```

[image: All]

Alliteratively you can use a like statement in your SQL and % as your default value.

```
where UPMCNOTIFICATIONCONTACTSM1.UPMC_ADDRESS like ?
and UPMCNOTIFICATIONCONTACTSM1.UPMC_FULL_NAME like ?
```

[image]

**BUT**

Null does not show in wild card searches.  So if you really have Null in your data, you may want to a SQL isnull() or a sub is null query

```
and ( UPMC_METADATA_DOMAIN like ?
or UPMC_METADATA_DOMAIN is null )
```